# Swift - Any - Cannot convert value of type MyType<Int> to expected element type MyType<protocol<>>

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, compiler-errors, any

I have listed below a fairly contrived example from something larger I am working on. I am encountering what I believe to be a Swift compiler bug regarding use of the Any type.

```
struct Labelable <T> {
  let t: T
  let label: String
}

func allLabels(labelables: [Labelable<Any>]) -> [String] {
  return labelables.map { $0.label }
}

let labeledInt = Labelable(t: 22, label: "Steve's Age")
let labeledString = Labelable(t: "Johnson", label: "Stacy's last name")

let labels = allLabels([labeledInt, labeledString])

print(labels)
```

Error in question:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Labelable<Int>' to expected element type 'Labelable<protocol<>>'
```

Does anyone have any insight into this issue and any workarounds? Or perhaps, there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is what I ended up doing. Ugh.

```
protocol LabelableProtocol {
  var label: String { get }
}

struct Labelable <T>: LabelableProtocol {
  let t: T
  let label: String
}

func allLabels(labelables: [LabelableProtocol]) -> [String] {
  return labelables.map { $0.label }
}

let labeledInt = Labelable(t: 22, label: "Steve's Age")
let labeledString = Labelable(t: "Johnson", label: "Stacy's last name")

let labels = allLabels([labeledInt, labeledString])

print(labels)
```

Comment: I think the problem is that Swift Generics are not covariant, nor contravariant. Generic concrete type equal only to the same concrete type. You can achieve what you want by using common protocol instead of Any type constraint. Check this blog post by mike ash https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Any` is not a type, but a protocol. You can see this by trying to extend it by another protocol (protocol extension by other protocols not allowed):

```
protocol MyDummyProtocol {}

extension Int : MyDummyProtocol {} // OK

extension Any : MyDummyProtocol {} 
    //Error: Non-nominal type Any (aka protocol<>) cannot be extended.
```

Hence, when calling `allLabels`, you cannot cast `Int` or `String` type to the `Any` protocol.

You could, however, specifically use `Any` as your generic `T` in your structure:

```
let labelAny = Labelable<Any>(t: 22, label: "Steve's Age")
let labelAnyAgain = Labelable<Any>(t: "Johnson", label: "Stacy's last name")

let labels = allLabels([labelAny, labelAnyAgain]) // OK
```

However, more interesting here is to study the generic property `t` in your structure. It should be `Any` now, right? The good thing about `Any` is that we can downcast it to fundamental swift types. E.g., consider:

```
struct Labelable <T> {
    let t: T
    let label: String
}

func allGenerics(labelables: [Labelable<Any>]) -> [Any] {
    return labelables.map { $0.t }
}

let labelAny = Labelable<Any>(t: 22, label: "Steve's Age")
let labelAnyAgain = Labelable<Any>(t: "Johnson", label: "Stacy's last name")

let labelsGeneric = allGenerics([labelAny, labelAnyAgain])

for label in labelsGeneric {
    switch label {
    case is Int: print("is int: " + "\(label)")
    case is String: print("is string: " + "\(label)")
    default: print("Default...")
    }
}
// Prints:
// is int: 22
// is string: Johnson
```

Here, we use `Any` as an generic (even if it is specifically an `Any`), and then simply let the down casting `is` be our generic behaviour.

See the [Language Guide - Type Casting - Type Casting for Any and AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) for details.

> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.
>
> ..
>
> Use Any and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and
>   capabilities they provide. It is always better to be specific about
>   the types you expect to work with in your code.

Comment: Hmmm. This is frustrating to me. "Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types." That sounds to me that any *thing* that can be represented in Swift, is in fact an Any. `print(12 as Any)` is fine.

What I wasn't clear about is I want `allLabels` to work. That's what I care about. Here is my workaround. I'm not happy with it, but...